# Simple ASCII encoding Q w/Java

Tags: java

I have a design idea for the following... In an app for playing solitaire/puzzle games, one of the things to do is to save/load games played from disk...  I would also like to feed saved games into game Applets as args and it will load that way.  There is a deal code (which shuffles the deck), which is in base 36, and in a saved game I have two other data structures with booleans and small integers - less than 36 - all will work as digits in base 36, or using just one case of letters and numerals, and a few punctuation characters as separators in the mix.

I don't know what I am up against in cross-platform ASCII in this case, but I would like to just write and read an ASCII string for a saved game with a set of about 40 ASCII characters.  I would like to be able to paste the same string into a web editor as the arg passed into an applet.

So the long and short of it is...  I am wondering what I have to do to deal with encoding for this, so this is a good, working cross-platform function (as described above)?

TIA - Mark

Answer (score 2):

If the user is using cut & paste then I would use base 64 as it is a simple string and unlikely to have trouble with that data entry method.  If they are TYPING then I would use base 26 or some such to avoid issues with 0 != O and 1 != l etc.  You may want to consider some kind of checksum or encryption to prevent cheating.

Comment: Hi, thx for the reply. The deal code is in base 36, and used with Java BigInt. Java base36 has letters and numerals. For any other game data, there are only booleans and integers less than 36, actually. If a person tries to edit such a string, their actions will not be supported, such as in a game competition where the data has value and needs to be secured. It will be secured, but not in its character encoding. When you say base 64, I'm not exactly sure what you mean.

Comment: base64 is a way to encode data in such a way that it's physically compact but doesn't contain any special characters.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64  I suggested base 26 (should have been base 32) if the users would be expected to type their "save codes" in since there's less chance of confusing similar looking digits. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base32

Comment: Thanks, Chris, for the pointer to base64... An online tool that shows encoding/decoding using base 16, 32, or 64... [Calculator](http://online-calculators.appspot.com/base64/)

Comment: You should be able to find a library for base64 in the language of your choice.  It's quite common.

Answer (score 0):

Since my program is the one both reading and writing the data files, I can maintain one encoding, such as UTF-8 or 16, for running on any platform.  I will not have to *support* reading anybody's hand-made data file (in an editor).

As for the paste operation, it seems that it will all be on the same machine.  I am guessing that going to the clipboard using the current default encoding will be fine from there (it knows its own encoding at that point, out of my hands).  I will draw the line of support at the string on the clipboard.  My program can read and write from the clipboard using the current default encoding (and require it has to work)

The difficulty I have with encoding is knowing where and when the change happens.  Please let me know if you think the data files above can be messed up by moving them from one machine to another.  Thx - Mark